# Proxy built-in errors?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to influence errors thrown from the JS compiler? In particular, I want to create my own error type `NullPointerException` and then proxy the built-in errors (such as `Error` and `TypeError`) to potentially return my custom exception.

Consider the following simple attempt (yes, they are global variables – but they are supposed to be):

```
NullPointerException = function (msg) {
    this.message = msg;
};

NullPointerException.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "NullPointerException: " + this.message;
};

var ProxyTypeError = TypeError;    
TypeError = function (msg) {
    if (msg.indexOf('null') === -1) {
        return new ProxyTypeError(msg);
    }

    return new NullPointerException(msg);
};
```

This will work fine for cases like

```
throw new TypeError('normal error'); // 'TypeError: normal error'
throw new TypeError('null'); // 'NullPointerException: null'
```

However, it won't work for the scenario I actually want it to work:

```
var obj = null;
console.log( obj.someMethod() ); // 'Uncaught TypeError: ...'
```

I am aware that browsers both use different messages and different errors, as well as that it's sketchy to even be wanting to do any of this. However, I'd still be interested if there is any actual solution to this? In the end, the use-case is something like

```
try {
    // ... code ...
} catch( e ) {
    if( e instanceof NullPointerException ) {
        // handle NPE separately
    }

    // do something else
}
```

wherein I do not have access to the `catch` part, hence my desire to throw the error accordingly.

Comment: No, you cannot change the engine's behaviour for accessing properties on `null`. You can only catch the thrown error.

Comment: I'm not planning on changing the behavior in the sense of not throwing the exception, just that I want to "proxy" the exception that was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to influence errors thrown from the JS interpreter?

No. However, if you want to throw your own errors you can do that for all exceptions that happened in your own code:

```
try {
    /* some code, possibly foreign */
    var obj = null;
    obj.someMethod()
} catch (e) {
    throw new CustomTypeError(e.msg);
}
```

but it would be much better to just check your types:

```
var obj = null;
if (obj == null)
    throw new NullPointerException();
else
    obj.someMethod();
```

Comment: I know it's better to do `null` checks, but like I said, part of this is not my code and I simply cannot control it. If I cannot proxy the "Uncaught TypeError" kind of exception, I guess this is just a feature I won't be able to implement.

Comment: (Well there sorta is *something* I can do in my particular situation, but it really is far from pretty…)

Comment: Yeah, if it's not your own code you can only catch the thrown normal exceptions and re-throw error objects of your own type; as I demonstrated above.